# Bulk Converting Data Using FME

Tags: shapefile, convert, file-geodatabase, fme-form

I am currently in the process of converting a large quantity of Ordnance Survey Vector Map Local data from .gz to Esri feature class within a file geodatabase. The process is working correctly but there is a limit to the number of .gz files FME will let me load/convert in one go. The error message simply says "there are too many recursive macro subsitutions". My knowledge of FME is limited so I was just wondering if there is a way to get around this as I currently have to keep loading sections of the data into the program.

Comment: In a very hi level overview - you can look at the process of batching using 'WorkspaceRunner' in combination with a reader 'Directory and File Pathnames' . The reader will list all of your .gz's and will feed their paths to WorkspaceRunner parameters triggering the .fmw that does the loading to the gbd. ( the one existent you have already ) . Its a parent / child process. Hope this helps

Comment: I think that is the answer (Directory Reader/WorkspaceRunner). That's how I would do it. Having said that, I don't like the sound of the "recursive macro substitutions" message. That I would file with the Safe support team.